# Параллельное выполнение PHP-файлов

Tags: php, javascript

Доброго.

Вот есть у нас 100 php-файлов, в каждом:

```
//для тестов
sleep(3);
//потом, что ни будь запишем в БД
```

Как можно выполнить код в php-файлах параллельно? Скажем, если последовательно, то придется ждать 5 минут. Параллельно - чуть более 3-х секунд.

Естественно, гуглил, и думал, как... знаю только include/required, но они последовательные.

P.S. Одна из тех тем, когда хочется создать левый ник на хэшкоде, чтобы не позориться. )

**Обновление**

Та-а-ак... Лыжи, оказывается, не едут и по тем примерам, ссылки на которые даны. И это для меня вообще тоска. Пример:

```
$ch1 = curl_init();
$ch2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, "sleep1.php");//sleep(15); - 15 сек
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, "sleep2.php");//sleep(20); - 20 сек
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$mh = curl_multi_init();
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch1);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch2);
$active = null;
do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    }
}
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch1);
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch2);
curl_multi_close($mh);
```

Печально, но в место 20 секунд выполнения скрипта он работает 35 (15+20)! Как, собственно, я в первом посте и описал.

Господа. Прошу, 1 рабочий пример. Верю, что может сработать, но рабочий код не видел.

Comment: как обрабатывается php на сервере? Бывают конфигурации, когда сколько бы ни было одновременных запросов, они выстраиваются в последовательную очередь к всего 1-3 "рабочим". По приведённому вами времени, похоже на то, что как раз всего 1 "рабочий" обрабатывает запросы.

Comment: Поначалу не обратил на этот коммент внимания, сейчас мысль дошла. Т.е. скрипт правильный? Или есть те, у кого он выполнился за 20 сек? Если да, то я так понимаю, нужно копать в сторону настройки сервера. Вот еще подсказали бы в какую. )

Comment: А зачем sleep?

Comment: так проще всего проверить. комп может сделать какое либо действие быстрее или медленнее. а sleep - так точно тормознет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обратись к каждому с помощью CURL. Вообще, что-то с логикой приложения не так.

**Обновление**

```
<?php

$var = echo shell_exec("/usr/bin/curl -L http://www.zend.com   http://zend.com/developers.php   
http://zend.com/zend/tut/");

?>
```

Подробнее http://phpclub.ru/detail/article/curl#part_2

Если можно js и разрешен прямой доступ к php-файлам, то в чем проблема в цикле на странице создавать новые iframe и указывать для них путь к необходимяым php файлам? Ограничения будут только из-за оперативки пользовательских ПК.

А держи, кстати, первая ссылка в Яндексе.

http://kocherov.net/parallel-curl-parallelnaya-zagruzka-i-obrabotka-stranits-v-php/

Comment: Уважаемый, можно скромный примерчик? Я дальше сам додумаю. В сторону CURL и AJAX уже копал, сломал лопату, и лыжи у меня не поехали. Но на путь истиный встать очень охота

Comment: Много iframe - уже пробовал, работает, но... Хром выдает предупреждение о пиратском ПО .) Кстати, по первой ссылке в яндексе, скрипт отработал все параллельно. Более менее адекватный пример с php.net - описал ниже. Он, как и остальные, выполняется последовательно.

Comment: @Get

> Обратись к каждому с помощью CURL.

Господи, фу

> Вообще, что-то с логикой приложения не так.

Это со словом "что-нибудь" в вопросе что-то не так, остальное терпимо.

@mixalef

> Как можно выполнить код в php файлах параллельно? 

1. https://github.com/kriswallsmith/spork
2. Банальный вызов в бэкграунд из консоли, https://github.com/Codegyre/Robo
3. http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pthreads.php

Answer (score 0):

[cURL умеет](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php) делать параллельно N запросов одной пачкой. Отсюда два варианта:

1) телепатия подсказывает, что, может, в каждом из 100 php файлов длинная задача – это запрос куда-то далеко. И тогда можно просто распараллелить все эти запросы внутри одного скрипта;
 2) если нет, а на сервере полно памяти, чтобы одновременно поднять 100 копий PHP, то надо одним скриптом просто дёрнуть сразу 100 ссылок на этом же сервере, которые одновременно запустят 100 процессов, которые обработают все задачи.

Намекните, какого рода задачи внутри ста скриптов заменят тестовый `sleep(3)`?

Comment: В место sleep - создаем много PDF. В конце каждого скрипта идет запись в бд, что такая то задача выполнена.

Comment: Создание PDF, наверное, интенсивная для процессора задача, и поэтому эффективно параллельно может работать не больше, чем ядер у процессора: 1, 4, 8? Я бы делал так:

1) нашёл конвертер, который работает из командной строки — незачем поднимать махину php для узкой задачи;  
2) бил объём задач на N равных частей (N - число процессоров в сервере).

Comment: Может, это поможет http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/os-php-multitask/